# Parallel transition in the Complex function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Here is the question my lecture gave to me in complex analysis class.

Find the image of the $x= 0$ for $T(z) = -2 + {2\over {z+1}}$ on complex plane.

(Hint :  $x = 1$ maps to circle its center is $({1 \over 2},0)$ with radius ${1 \over 2}$ considering the $z \to {1 \over z}$)

So he solved this question like the below.

Say the $C_1$ : a circle whose center $({1 \over 2},0)$ with radius ${1 \over 2}$ on complex plane.

$T(z)$ is a composition of the $z \to z+1, z \to {1 \over z}, z \to 2z$ and $z \to z-2$ in sequence.

I agreed his solution so far. But Suddenly, he claimed the weird things.

Consideing the $T(z)$, Then $T(z)$ is  a mapping such that   $x=0 \to x=1$, $x=1 \to C_1$ and $C_1 \to C_2$ in consecutively.

(Here the $C_2$ is a twice time of the $C_1$ and parallel transition by "$-2$" on the $x$-axis(real axis) in order.)

So, I have a doubt about his solution. Because, generally for claiming parallel transition by $"a"$ and $"b"
$ on the $x, y$ axis respectively, functions should be $f(x,y) \to f(x-a,y-b)$ on the other hand case of the point  $(x,y) \to (x+a, y+b)$.

Hence does it have to be $x=0 \to x=-1$ for claiming $z \to z+1 $?

I'm really confused. What is the difference what I've known? Please help me.

p.s.) My lecture regarded $z \to z-2$ parallel transition by $"-2"$ on the real axis like he did the $z \to z+1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure that I have understood which part of your instructor's solution that you don't understand, but if you feel unsure about translation in general, you may rest assured that the mapping $z \mapsto z + a$ for a complex number $a$ corresponds to translation by $a$. This follows from the fact that complex addition has the same geometric interpretation as vector addition. In particular this means that the mapping $z \mapsto z+1$ maps the line $\{z | \Re(z) = 0 \}$ to the line $\{z | \Re(z)=1 \}$, i.e. it moves the line one unit to the right. I hope this brough some clarity.

Comment: You've totally understood what I meant. Surely$ z \to z+a$ is transition by $a \in \mathbb C$. But my question is if we express this by function, $f(z)$, that would be $f(z-a)$. so considering the my instructor's solution there should be" -1 transition" Not the "1 "the reason why given formula is  $2/(z+1)$ NOT the $2/(z-1)$ I thought. So I can't  understand why he claim "1 transition". :(

Comment: I think that you are applying an idea from calculus with real numbers that does not work the same way in $\mathbb{C}$. It is indeed correct that if $f$ is a real function of a real variable, you can translate its graph $a$ units to the right by plotting $f(x-a)$. Now, think carefully about what this really means: You are subtracting $a$ in the argument, effectively translating the x-axis to the left. I think this should make it easier to see what is really the connection between +/- and right/left translation.

Comment: Ah? Then.. Unlike the real case,  if we considering the $T : z \to z+a$(parallel transition) in complex, then $T \circ f(z)$ is $f(z+a)$ ? (Surely The real case, $T \circ f(z) = f(z-a)$) Would you please check my idea, Mr. fenris?

Comment: If $T$ is the translation you describe, $T \circ f$ will be the mapping $z \mapsto f(z)+a$. There is a difference between $T \circ f$ and $f \circ T$. Whether you translate before or after you apply $f$ matters.

Comment: Err.... Sorry for typo. I meant $f \circ T$ which the $T$ I described.

Comment: Then you have understood the order of composition correctly. In the real case however, translation by $a$ is an ambigous term because you need to specify along which axis you translate. As a matter of fact, that once again comes back to whether you translate before or after applying $f$. If you translate before, i.e. take $f(x-a)$, you translate along the x-axis. Whereas if you take $f(x)-a$ you translate along the y-axis.

Comment: It really does. Thanks for your kind answer. :)